# Load a library in a model in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Why won't my model load the encryption library?

```
class User_model extends Model {

  function User_model() {
    parent::Model();
    $this->check_login();
  }

  function check_login() {
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $email = $this->encrypt->decode($email);
    ....
  }
}
```

This giving me a PHP error: Call to a member function decode() on a non-object on line X -- where X is the $this->encrypt->decode($email); line?

*Edited to show that the problem was that check_login was called from the constructor*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was calling check_login from within the constructor, and that was causing the problems.

The solution is to call `$this->_assign_libraries();` right after loading a library in a constructor.

Thanks to this codeignitor forum thread:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/145537/

Comment: I know this thread is very old, but if you see this be aware that the current version of CI allows you to load Libraries in Models without any issues.

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to load the library in the MODEL, MODELS are always called from the CONTROLLERS so you just have to load the Libraries in the Controller, and the functions will be available in the models called from him!

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: Yes, but loading libraries where they're needed minimizes dependency issues.

Comment: So load it in the just in controller function that call the model

Comment: What a crappy idea! Seriously, Another short sighted blunder by the CodeIgniter team! A model is a perfect place to consume an API library  that deals with getting application data! Force me to load a library in the controller that an underlying Model class depends on!?? What the hell? Screw that! Just call $this->_assign_libraries(); done!

Comment: I know this is an old question but to update with info on the newest version of CI: I'm using CI v.2.0.2 and I can successfully load a model from the controller and have that model load and access the library.  I've run into a few case sensitive problems with loading as Library but having to access it as library but that might well be a configuration problem on my localhost or CI setup.

Answer (score 6):

Libraries should automatically be assigned to the Model instance so it should work fine.

Remember if you can't access the super-global you can always use $ci =& get_instance() to grab it at no extra cost to your memory.

But still... your code example should work >.<

Answer (score 5):

I have tried many of them, but in the end, what I did is this in a model:

```
$this->load->library('mylib');
$mylib= new Mylib();
$mylib->somemethod();
```

This works for me.

Comment: for ci 4 refer https://roytuts.com/codeigniter-4-load-third-party-library/#:~:text=First%20step%20is%20to%20auto,%3E%20%22ThirdParty%2Ftcpdf%22%20%5D%3B

Answer (score 0):

you might want to change the name of the object for the library you are loading
beacause CI also has got the encrypt class

just do

```
$this->load->library('encrypt',NULL,'myencryptobj');
$this->myencryptobj->yourfunction();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing issue about facebook api, then I tried required_once the lib file of facebook in model. it worked for me.

require_once "application/libraries/facebook.php";
then make its object if you need.