# Load a library file in a model file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to load library file from model in codeigniter. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Why you are not including it in controller ? any specific reason ?

Comment: possible duplicate: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365591/load-a-library-in-a-model-in-codeigniter

Comment: @jpec its not working for me

Comment: @asim yes. because i have call too many function in model file. thats why am asking.

Comment: Still you don't  need to call it in models,load it in controllers it will be available in model that you have loaded in that specific controller,Anyways see my below answer @MansoorH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always load the libraries in controller,as models are always called from controllers.

Anyways you can try like this:

```
$this->load->library('library_name');
$lib= new library_name();
$lib->somemethod();
```

Comment: Glade to help you @MansoorH

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in the library folder and use the following code to load it in the controller:

`$this->load->library('your_library');`

Remember, do NOT put your code in the system folder's library folder. Put it in the appilcation's library folder.

Once loaded, you can use the classes defined in your library. Remember, libraries work different than models. For Example:

Your library:
`<? class Foo{ Foo() {} function Bar() {} } ?>` saved as `myFoo.php` in `application/library/`

Load it like
`$this->load->library('myFoo');`
then use it like
`$foo = new Foo();
$bar = $foo->Bar();`