# CodeIgniter 3: Loading a library on MY_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created a class MY_Model from which all my models inherit from. Inside it I have a method called switchConnection. Inside it I need to use system library encryption.

I know that in a model $this refers to the model so I can not do:

```
$this->load->library('encryption')
```

I have tried loading the library using:

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->load->library('encryption');
$ci->encryption->decrypt(....);
```

but I get the same error: Trying to get property of non-object.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to autoload the library and check it.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I have add it to autoload.php, in libraries, but it did not work either

Comment: ok, so it worked in controller ?

Comment: yes, at controller level it works

Comment: load library from `autoload` is fine, in model remove `$ci->load->library('encryption');` and try it may work with `$ci = & get_instance();`

Comment: you have get many successful answer in the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365591/load-a-library-in-a-model-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
$myEncryption = new CI_Encryption();
$myEncryption->decrypt($string);
```

Class name is CI_Encryption

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the space between '=' and '&'.

So try this way ->

```
$ci =& get_instance();
```